# Cannot install Ubuntu from Startup Disk due to error?

Tags: dual-boot, usb-installation

I tried to setup a new computer today.  Windows 10 on half an SSD is installed and working but Ubuntu, meant for the other half, is not and my attempts to fix this fails.  I have tried using the startup disk creator that comes with Ubuntu to setup an USB with some ISOs from ubuntu.com.

15.10 simply says "boot error" and does not work.  I saw a post on this forum saying it just cannot be installed in the normal way so I moved on.

14.04 lets me select a language but when choosing either "install" or "try without", it says there is a firmware error and something about i915.  Did not find a matching error anywhere (someone was complaining a long time ago about a copying issue but that was all) so I guessed the kernel was too old or something.  Seems ridiculous if that is the case.

16.04 daily build also lets e choose a language but when selecting any of the options for moving along with the installation, it just freezes my screen in a black screen of death.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?  What more information might be needed to solve this?

I have a 6700K i7 processor and my graphics card is a gtx 980 ti. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

The reason that you are getting the "black screen of death" in 16.04 is because your graphics card is very new and therefore is only supported by recent versions of drivers. I also believe that you need the proprietary drivers to get NVIDIA 9xx cards working :(

### A temporary solution

When you boot into the live medium, disable kernel mode setting. You can do this by pressing F6 and selecting `nomodeset`. After this you should be able to boot into the live installer.

[image: Screenshot of boot menu].

### A more permanent solution

After you have installed 16.04, you need to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. When the computer boots back up, go to `System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers`. In there, select `Using NVIDIA binary driver`.

Reboot and cross your fingers; everything should work fine now.

[image: Screenshot of driver selection].

Comment: Thank you!  (delayed realization that it worked but I did not report on it.)